# VS2008 & AnkhSVN: Any way to get the "Show Changes" to ignore whitespace?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, ankhsvn

Is there a way to configure AnkhSVN so the default "show changes", under the right-click context menu, ignores whitespace diffs?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the easiest way to reach this, is to install a diff viewer that allows you to toggle whitespace differences and configure AnkhSVN to use that diff viewer. [SourceGear Diffmerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) works great for this.

Answer (score 0):

AnkhSVN uses the SharpSVN-API to perform SVN-related operations. 
So it depends on how the API's diff-function is implemented. 
For such reasons and because there are no configuration options, I don't
think it's possible without touching SharpSVN's and/or AnkhSVN's source 
code. You could suggest the developers to implement such feature for 
future releases... of course there no guarantee they will implement it.

Comment: See http://feedback.ankhsvn.net/forums/3267-general/suggestions/37055-add-option-to-ignore-whitespace-changes?ref=title for the uservoice item about this.